# How to power a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with DC-DC Boost Convertor module (3.5v to 5v) via GPIO Pins

Tags: alternative-power

I am trying to power up a Raspberry Pi 3B+ via GPIO pins and have read about the specs to provide 5V input voltage. Since there are no batteries that can directly output 5v - i had to fallback to 3.7V battery(s).

I am using a 3.7v to 5v DC-DC Boost module (XL6009 DC-DC Step-up Module (3.7v to 5v)) to bring up the voltage to 5v to power the PI. I see that it ends up in a boot loop. The Pi itself is perfectly fine and boots when connected to a Micro USB port.

Although the output of the Boost module is 5v, from the GPIO pins on the PI, i see 6v+ detected on the multi-meter and a msg while booting up saying that the voltage is high.

I have also experimented on a 9V->5V DC-DC Buck module and that seems to be work properly and the Pi boots up all fine and the GPIO pin voltage is just 5v as expected.

Looking for some help understanding why the Boost module with 3.7v doesn't work.

p.s - I am aware that i will be by-passing the Pi's power protection if i use GPIO ports - But i need to use them for a project that i am building.

edit1 - Updated the boost module name.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi, why a " 3.7v to 5v DC-DC Boost module" is not living up to the specification. And Please post model and schema of the " 3.7v to 5v DC-DC Boost module" and post it in SE Electrical Engineering.

Comment: Done, updated the post with the boost module that i am using.

Comment: xl6009 is a 1A capable module, you’ll see undervoltage and crashes

Answer (score 1):

Don't feed 6V into a Pi.  You will destroy the Pi.

The highest voltage I have risked is 5.8V (but I knew that if the Pi was destroyed it would be my fault).

As well as the proper voltage (nominally 5V plus or minus 0.25 volts) you need to supply sufficient current.  Note that a 2.5 amp power supply is suggested for the Pi3B+.  You will probably only need an amp or so if you are running with few peripherals.

I expect the boost converter is not supplying enough current.

Comment: 5.25V is the recommended maximum.

Comment: I see 1Amp current only being passed by the boost module. 

The same was being passed by the buck convertor (9v-5v) too but it boots fine. 

Right now, no extra sensors or peripherals are connected so its just the Raspberry Pi 3B+ or 3A+.

Comment: 1 amp is marginal at best.  If that's the limit of the boost converter you need a more capable model.